# Number of solutions of a matrix algebraic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Reading [that](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9410207), I found that:

> given a matrix algebraic equation $$ X^n+A_1X^{n-1}+\cdots + A_n=0 $$ 
>   where the cofficients $A_1\cdots,A_n$ as well as solutions $X$ are
>   supposed to be square complex matrices of some order $k$.......
>   generically has $\binom {nk}{k}$ rather $n$ solutions.

Someone know how can we prove this statement, or where I can find a proof?

Comment: Is that true ? Take $n = 2$ and $k = 2$ then all the matrices of the form $\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ z & -i \end{bmatrix}$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$ are solutions of $X^{2} + \mathrm{I}_{2} = 0$. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I agree. And also the matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}-i&z\\0&i\end{bmatrix}$. So I suppose that the statement in OP refers to the number of linearly independent solutions. But this is one of my troubles in interpreting the statement.

Comment: It is probably true that there are $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} nk \\ k \end{pmatrix}$ distinct solutions if there are no relations, with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, linking the entries of $A_{1},\ldots,A_{n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at pages 2,4,5 (Theorem 1) of my following paper (free advertising) http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2506

A slightly different version is submitted to LAA.

Answer to Emilio. 1. In fact, an old version (v2) is posted on arXiv. A recent one (v3) will be readable from March 3.

2. A simple solution has multiplicity $1$. (cf. def. 3,ex. 1,def. 4,ex. 2).
3. The considered result is valid when $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ are generic matrices (cf. def. 1). For instance, if you randomly choose the $(A_i)_i$, then (except if you are very unlucky), you obtain the required number of simple solutions.
4. About "... the matrices $X_h$ that are solutions of the equation (1) are ALL the matrices that have as eigenvalues...". "ALL" is incorrect: we choose $k$ values amongst the $nk$ roots of (2); then we construct the unique solution that admits these $k$ values as eigenvalues. In particular the complexity of the problem (1) is the complexity of the resolution of(2).

Comment: Thank You, I will read it.

Comment: very interesting reference! what do you means exatly for **simple** solutions in Th. 1 ?

Comment: I've sent an answer that is a sum up of your paper. I'll be grateful if you control if I've well understood your result, and if it's well summed up. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this OP is in the paper cited by @loup blanc.
I added this post only to complete the initial question with an answer easily accessible to readers that sums up the main result in the paper.

It seems that the statement that an equation of the form:
$$
(1) \qquad A_nX^n+A_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots + A_0=0
$$ 
(where  $A_i$ and $X$ are square complex matrices of order $k$) has $\binom {nk}{k}$ solutions, was found by J.J. Sylvester, but was communicated without a proof.

The proof given in the cited paper shows that the matrices $X_h$ that are solutions of the equation $(1)$ are matrices that have as eigenvalues $k$ numbers $\{\lambda_i\}\quad (\lambda_1 \in \{1,\cdots,nk\})$ , where the $\lambda_i$ are solutions of the equation:
$$
(2) \qquad \mbox{det}\left(\lambda^n A_n+ \cdots+\lambda A_1+A_0\right)=0
$$
that is obviously an  equation of degree $nk$, so the $X_h$ are exactly $\binom {nk}{k}$.

In the paper it's also proved that the Galois group of $(2)$ is $S_{nk}$ so the entries of the solution of $(1)$ can be calculated by radicals if and only if $n=k=2$.